# how to handle this error when user search but didn't pass anything and found this kind of error in Django but user input id it work

Tags: python, django

views.py

```
def paitent(request):
    
    search_query = ''
    
    if request.GET.get('search_query'):
        
        search_query = request.GET.get('search_query')
        if search_query == ' ':
            print('Ex')

        else:
            userprofile = Profile.objects.filter(id=search_query)
            profiles =  Totallcount.objects.filter(image_owner=search_query)
            

    context = {
       'profiles':profiles,
       'userprofile':userprofile,
     
    }
    return render(request, "medical_report/paitent.html",context)
```

paitent.html

```
        <form class="d-flex ms-auto my-3 my-lg-0" id='searchForm' action="{% url 'paitent' %}" method="get">
          <div class="input-group">

            <input
              class="form-control"
              type="search"
              placeholder="Search by Name"
              aria-label="Search"
              id="formInput#search" type="text" name="search_query" value="" />
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Search">
              <i class="bi bi-search"></i>
            </button>
            
          </div>
        </form>
```

Error.

---

```
UnboundLocalError at /paitent/
local variable 'profiles' referenced before assignment
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/paitent/?search_query=
Django Version: 3.2.15
Exception Type: UnboundLocalError
Exception Value:    
local variable 'profiles' referenced before assignment
Exception Location: C:\Users\21100002\Desktop\myreports\medical_report\views.py, line 176, in paitent
Python Executable:  C:\Users\21100002\Desktop\ocr\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.0
```

Comment: Why are you calling *request.GET.get('search_query')* twice?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this section:

```
if request.GET.get('search_query'):
    
    search_query = request.GET.get('search_query')
    if search_query == ' ':
        print('Ex')

    else:
        userprofile = Profile.objects.filter(id=search_query)
        profiles =  Totallcount.objects.filter(image_owner=search_query)
        
context = {
   'profiles':profiles,
   'userprofile':userprofile,
}
return render(request, "medical_report/paitent.html",context)
```

If `search_query` is equal to whitespace `" "`, then it prints (`'Ex'`) and move to context, where it needs `profiles`, but it didn't set that variable. You need to create proper values in `if search_query == ' '` and add `else` for `if request.GET.get('search_query')` condition, in example like this:

```
if request.GET.get('search_query'):

    search_query = request.GET.get('search_query')
    if search_query == ' ':
        print('Ex')
        userprofile = Profile.objects.all()
        profiles =  Totallcount.objects.all()

    else:
        userprofile = Profile.objects.filter(id=search_query)
        profiles =  Totallcount.objects.filter(image_owner=search_query)

else:
    userprofile = Profile.objects.all()
    profiles =  Totallcount.objects.all()

context = {
   'profiles': profiles,
   'userprofile': userprofile,
}
return render(request, "medical_report/paitent.html",context)
```

Every variable you use has to be firstfully set in every possible way in your algorithm.

Comment: That won't work if request.GET.get('search_query') returns a falsy value

Answer (score 0):

Consider what happens if:

```
if request.GET.get('search_query')
```

...returns a falsy value.

In such a case neither *userprofile* nor *profiles* will exist yet you try to use then unconditionally in you *context* dictionary construction